# Bandgap and crystal orientation

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Some of us are designing an experiment to measure the bandgap of intrinsic semiconductor wafer. For that we need rectangular 2D pieces of the semiconductor material.

I want to know if the bandgap of semiconductor material depends on the crystal orientation in which it was cut.

Comment: band gap depends on the properties of the composition of the material rather than mechanical properties. So I guess the orientation won't affect the bandgap

Comment: I suspected the same but since the typical measurement of band gap involves measuring the conductivity of the material I was wondering if orientation would make any difference.

Comment: The 'typical' measurement of a band gap is done through spectroscopy, not measurements of conductivity. Further, for a non-cubic semiconductor material, it is quite possible (even quite likely) that conductivity varies with crystal direction.

Comment: But measuring the conductivity of the semiconductor as a function of varying temperature can give you bandgap as well. That is what we are trying to make.

Comment: 've done a little memory jog and have a possible answer.  so I'll put this into an answer below

Comment: The band gap is a characteristic of the material and does not depend on the orientation of the crystal. The band *structure* however obviously does depend on the orientation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: The answer requires some knowledge of solid state physics. In particular, I assume that concepts like *dispersion relation*, *reciprocal space* and *effective mass* are familiar to you.

The band gap is a fixed characteristic of the material. It does not depend on the crystal orientation. In the band diagram, it is the minimum vertical separation of the conduction and valence bands. The exact momentum (and correspondingly, the crystal axis) which determine the gap are irrelevant to its definition. For a direct semiconductor (e.g. GaAs, InP, but not Si) the gap is even located at the origin of momentum space!

Now it is indeed the case that for different directions in momentum space, the carrier dispersion may look slightly different. Consequently, the effective mass is different, and also carrier mobility. However, when applying an electric field, you do not exclusively excite electrons and holes traveling parallel to the field. Some also move at an angle to it, but together, their net contribution to the axes perpendicular to the field vanishes.

Let us look at it in a different way.

If conductivity depends on the crystal orientation, it must be a tensor. Ohm's law then reads:
$$ j_k = \sum_{l\in \{x,y,z\}}\sigma_{kl}E_l$$
As is explained on [this forum (post #9)](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/si-conductivity-depenence-on-crystal-orientation.632467/), for any material with cubic symmetry (e.g. Si, Ge, GaAs), we find that $\sigma_{kl}$ must be constant. In other words, conductivity *does not* depend on the orientation.

Answer (score -2):

[image: electron energy as a function of interatomic distance]

In the picture attached with the answer you can see how the interatomic distance affects the electron energy. This happens because the energy bandgap is directly affected by the periodic potential. Now consider 2 crystal directions. Then in one direction your atomic periodicity is *a* and in the other direction(diagonal maybe) it is $\sqrt[]{2a}$. The periodic potential will look different and the bandgap will change accordingly.

In fact, for due to the anisotropy all properties like thermal conductivity, electrical conductivity, RI will be different in different direction.

This is what my reasoning tells me. Lets discuss if there's any problem.

Comment: It does not work that way. The band gap is defined as the energy range over which the density of states is zero. It does not depend on the crystal orientation. 
@Sad_lab_rat: In your example you would need to somehow 'superimpose' both density of states, and the region where there were still no states available would define the band gap. It is not quite as simple as that though, so I'll leave it there.

Comment: Doesn\t conductivity decrease exponentially with bandgap? I kow of experiments where you use the conductivity vs temperature relation to obtain activation energy and thus determine the bandgap. Wouldn't we get different values of bandgap from these conductivities measured in different directions? 
I know that '\m somehow wrong but I can't point it out exactly. because I've never heard of bandgap being mentioned alongside crystal orientation

Comment: I think there's a superposition of the wavefunctions to give a net bandgap for the whole crystal hence making it independent of orientation?

Comment: So the idea in these experiments is that the conductivity is measured as a function of temperature. The way I see it, the equation goes like, $\ln(\sigma) =\ln(\sigma_0)- E_g/2k_BT. For the same temperature range, if the band gap is constant then the conductivity is arbitrary by the constant \ln(\sigma_0). So it is still possible that the bandgap is not effected by electrical conduction. Either that or I am totally off the spot!

Comment: @Sad_lab_rat No, you don't superimpose wave functions each solving one axis of the crystal lattice potential. Schrödinger's equation does not allow that.